# onClick handler is triggered on each render cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have default state like this

```
this.state = {
  selectedTab : 'tab1'
}
```

then

My render method like this

```
render(){
   const { selectedTab } = this.state;
   return(
      <li>tab1</li><li>tab2</li>
      <div id="content">
         {selectedTab == 'tab1' ? this.renderTab1Content() : this.renderTab2Content()}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Everything worked above. But I failed to implement switch tab using click event.

I tried to bind onclick event on my `li` to change the state of selectedTab, but I got infinity loop error. Like this

```
<li onClick={this.setState({selectedTab :'tab1'})}>Tab 1</li>
<li onClick={this.setState({selectedTab :'someothertab'})}>Tab 2/li>
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because you `onClick` handler expects a function but you have called a statement to setState on the event and hence everytime you state changes using `setState`, the render is called again and hence the `onClick` again calls the `setState` which triggers an infinite loop. You can do  this by using an `arrow function` in `onClick` event or calling a separate function

```
<li onClick={() => this.setState({selectedTab :'tab1'})}>Tab 1</li>
```

or

```
handleClick = () =>{
    this.setState({selectedTab :'tab1'})
}


<li onClick={this.handleClick}>Tab 1</li>
```

Comment: oh this is a careless mistake!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I will introduce concept of **"higher order functions here"**.

Basicaly, higher order function is function returning another function.

Let's modify `onClick` handler and make it "higher order function".

```
// Original function
setActiveTab = (activeTab) => {
  this.setState({ activeTab });
}

// Higher order function
setActiveTab = (activeTab) => {
  // Here, we already "remember" name of tab which becomes active after click.
  // Return "true" `onClick` handler from this place.
  return () => {
    // Finaly set state after click.
    this.setState({ activeTab });
  }
}
```

How will render function look like?

```
<li onClick={this.setActiveTab('tab1')}>Tab 1</li>
<li onClick={this.setActiveTab('someothertab')}>Tab 2/li>
```

Better, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Every time your `li` gets rendered, the setState is automatically called and hence you get into a loop.  You should do something like this.

Create a method in the component like this

```
setActiveTab = (tab) => {
 this.setState({selectedTab : tab});
}
```

Then in your render method rewrite your `li` like this

```
<li onClick={() => this.setActiveTab('tab1')}>Tab 1</li>
<li onClick={() => this.setActiveTab('someothertab')}>Tab 2/li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever setState is called it causes render method to be run,
and when u assign a function call instead of a function refrence to some variable, it calls it instantly.

In your case your function refrence, setState is called instantly on assignment and further setState calls render again, which further causes the setState call -> setState render, this creates an endless loop.

```
<li onClick={this.setState({selectedTab :'tab1'})}>Tab 1</li>
```

Render -> onclick => setState -> Render -> onclick => setState -> ....

**To overcome this there are two ways,**

You can use arrow functions, which also helps you to bind this reference of class to the function.

```
onClick={() => (this.setState())}
```

or if using simple function then you can bind them in the constructor.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.onClickMethod = this.onClickMethod.bind(this);
// if this is not done then this in onclick method would not refer to the class 
// instead it would that of assigned onClick callback as it is called 
// by onclick Event handler hence exectuted in different context.
}

onClickMethod() {
 this.setSate();
}

<li onClick={this.onClickMethod}>Tab 1</li>
```